# Change language on Android

Tags: android, multilingual

I use below code to change language:

```
res.getConfiguration().locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
```

It works.
But according to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).
Some language not exist, such as Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, it cannot be set by this Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE.
I mean Locale. not contains these language, but not that after set not work.
How can I set these language.

Comment: If it is not available, probably the device doesn't support those languages.

Comment: Some device doesn't support some languages... You have to set it to dynamically.

Comment: try this link may be useful for you http://venkoolit.blogspot.in/2013/08/android-localization-demo.html